# SPS format of representative sequence from seqrep

Tags: traminer

Does anyone know how to extract the representative sequences form seqrep output, given in SPS format? It would be very helpful for viewers of the plot from seqrplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the output with the `format = 'SPS'` argument. I illustrate with the `biofam` data

```
data(biofam)
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab)

## Computing the distance matrix
costs <- seqcost(biofam.seq, method="INDELSLOG")
biofam.om <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method="OM", sm=costs$sm, indel=costs$indel)

## Representative set using the neighborhood density criterion
biofam.rep <- seqrep(biofam.seq, diss=biofam.om, criterion="density")
print(biofam.rep, format="SPS")

##     Sequence         
## [1] (0,16)           
## [2] (0,9)-(3,1)-(6,6)
## [3] (0,6)-(1,10)
```

And if you want to retrieve the representative sequences in SPS form, you can use `seqformat` and `seqconc`:

```
biofam.rep.sps <- seqconc(seqformat(biofam.rep, to='SPS'))
```

The result is a single column matrix with each representative sequence stored as a character string.

Comment: Is it possible to have representative by cluster, using group= the cluster factor?

Comment: This is another question and you would be best initiate another thread for it. But sure you can get representatives by cluster by using the `seqrep.grp` function of `TraMineRextras`.

Comment: @ Gilbert. Thank you!